# Update BottomNavigationBar when tapping on Button

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm looking for a way to update the backgroundColor of the `BottomNavigationBar` when the user taps on a button. The problem here is the `BottomNavigationBar` aren't in the same file as the button. My application is divided into two files. The first file, **main.dart**, includes a StatefulWidget with a `BottomNavigationBar`. The other file, **home.dart**, has a StatefulWidget too with a button. The question is how to update the `BottomNavigationBar` when the user tapping on the button? Basically with calling setState() everything is fine, but as I said the `BottomNavigationBar` is located in an other file. I've absolutely no idea and I'm not sure if this is even possible.

I added no code because I'm not really asking for code snippets but rather food for thought or explanations what I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your bottom navigation bar file as Stateless shown in this dart pad example

[Example on Github](https://github.com/viveky259259/flutter_for_people/blob/master/lib/randomuis/dynamic.bottomnavigation.dart)

In this on click of press button color of bottom navigation bar changes

Let me know if it work out or not for you.

Comment: In the example nothing changes. Can you please check the example again?

Comment: hey click on press button you will changes in bottom navigation bar

Comment: There is no bottom navigation bar https://imgur.com/a/pCRck5t

Comment: Here you go https://github.com/viveky259259/flutter_for_people/blob/master/lib/randomuis/dynamic.bottomnavigation.dart .    Go to this link and run this program. It should solve your problem

Comment: I needed to add `MaterialApp` and `void main() ...` to run the code, but it works now. Wow, thank you very much.